# Stacking tensors in a list of tuples of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have a list of tuples of PyTorch tensors. It looks like this:

```
[
    (tensor([1, 2, 3]),  tensor([4, 5, 6, 7]),  tensor([8])),
    (tensor([9, 10,11]), tensor([11,12,13,14]), tensor([15])),
    (tensor([16,17,18]), tensor([19,20,21,22]), tensor([23])),
    ...
]
```

Tensors in each column (that is, tensors that position k of their respective tuple) share the same shape. I want to stack the tensors in each column so that I end up with a single tuple, each value being the tensors concatenated along the dimension of the column.

In this case, the output tuple would have three values, and look like this:

```
(
 tensor([[1,2,3], [9,10,11], [16,17,18]]),

 tensor([[4,5,6,7], [11,12,13,14], [19,20,21,22]],

 tensor([[8],[15],[23])
)
```

This is a made-up example. I want to do this for tuples of any length, and tensors of arbitrary size. What is the best way to do this type of concatenation quickly using PyTorch?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone gets themselves into the same convoluted scenario, I was able to solve it with a lovely one-liner:

```
tuple(map(torch.stack, zip(*x)))
```

In this case, `x` is the original list I mentioned above. This line of code transforms `x` into the exact desired format.

Comment: I think you have meant `torch.stack` instead of `torch.tensor`

Comment: great solution, thanks. btw, I needed to stack the tensors on the first dim- for that torch.cat provided the solution